# How do I convert this JS to CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I will eventually learn how to write CoffeeScript, but I just need this translated into CoffeeScript right now. Anyone care to take a stab at it?

```
function animate_favorite($favorite) {

  $favorite.addClass('active');

  var card = $favorite.parent().parent().parent();
  var card_id = card.attr('id');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#' + card_id).find('.card-favorite-count').removeClass('active');
  },1200);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is **[Js2Coffee](http://js2.coffee/)** verry simple website that convert in the both ways Js to coffee and the opposite.

**Your coffee code :**

```
animate_favorite = ($favorite) ->
  $favorite.addClass 'active'
  card = $favorite.parent().parent().parent()
  card_id = card.attr('id')
  setTimeout (->
    $('#' + card_id).find('.card-favorite-count').removeClass 'active'
    return
  ), 1200
  return
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about this!